# Error in uploading image when using cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

when developing locally, i was able to upload images in storage directory, but now as the diectory sructure changed a bit.
Now Intervention is showing an error.
Error is

```
message: "Image source not readable", exception: "Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException",…}
exception: "Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException"
```

This is my controller

```
public function submitAddProduct(Request $request){

        $data = $request->validate([
            'image' => ['required','image'],
            'image_second' => ['required','image']
        ]);

        //dd(request('image')->store('uploads','public'));

        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads','public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"));
        $image->save();

        $imagePath2 = request('image_second')->store('uploads','public');

        $image2 = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath2}"));
        $image2->save();

        $dataVal = $request->all();

        $dataVal['image'] = $imagePath;
        $dataVal['image_second'] = $imagePath2;

        // d3d($dataVal);

        $d = Products::create($dataVal);

        $id = $d->id;

        if($id){
            $arr = array('msg' => $id);
        }
        return Response()->json($arr);
    }
```

it should get stored in the uploads directory.
My cpanel directory structure is as follows
The public_html contains

[image]

And the system folder inside the public_html contains
[image]

The symlinks are working fine, as i can see images that were previously present in uploads.
symlink.php is

```
<?php
symlink('/home//public_html/system/storage/app/public','/home//public_html/storage');
```

Only the first Image gets uploaded to storage/uploads and then interventions shows error.

Please Help